# How to improve trajectory of rocket (Unity 3d)

Tags: unity-game-engine, simulation, physics, game-physics

I have a sphere with attached empty object, the object is on the planet's surface, rocket launches from this empty object. Sphere is rotating.
My rocket can fly by spiral trajectory from a center of it's instantiating place. The problem that I can't resolve is that rocket's trajectory is independent from planet's rotation.
This is Update() function for the rocket:

```
void Update () {
     angle += speed * Time.deltaTime;
     x = Mathf.Cos (angle) * radius;
     z = Mathf.Sin (angle) * radius;
     rb.velocity = new Vector3(x,0.0f,z);
     radius += stepOfRadius;
 }
```

What I have:
[image]

How I want it to be (without moon and returning back to Earth):
[image]

Comment: "The problem that I can't resolve is that rocket's trajectory is independent from planet's rotation" is it possible that simply, you have the rocket as a child of the planet? **if so, detach it.**  use `.parent=` to set the parent of a Transform - such as `= null`  - google 100000s of pages on that.

Comment: well if you are trying to maintain exact control of what's going on you should NOT use unity physics for trajectories - only for collision checking, triggering stuff, etc. And yes, the reason your ship has declared independence is also the product of Unity Physics engine. I strongly encourage you to do the calculations in FixedUpdate and manually move your ship. You can maintain a local "velocity" variable to guide yourself and you will be sure no other magic is taking place behind the scene.

Comment: Won't using the n-body algorithm work here?

Comment: Did you try my answer ?

Comment: @cromod yes, see comment below your answer

Comment: you should, of course, use "Unity's physics".  (PhysX.)  It is incredibly easy to use, unless you have no knowledge of programming. It can trivially achieve the desired flight here.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a lot about unity3d but x and z seem to be the components of position and not velocity.

If it's possible, try to replace

```
rb.velocity = new Vector3(x,0.0f,z);
```

by

```
rb.position = new Vector3(x,0.0f,z);
```

or

```
Vector3 position(x,0.0f,z);
rb.MovePosition(position);
```

---

Otherwise, you can keep `rb.velocity` by defining this components of velocity (I suppose `speed` is an angular velocity):

```
 x = (stepOfRadius/Time.deltaTime) * Mathf.Cos(angle) - radius * speed * Mathf.Sin(angle);
 z = (stepOfRadius/Time.deltaTime) * Mathf.Sin(angle) + radius * speed * Mathf.Cos(angle);
```

Comment: With `rb.position = new Vector3(x,0.0f,z);` rocket become independent not only from Earth but also from launch place, and rocket always starts from bottom of the planet. The other code also didn't help.

Comment: Sorry I don't know unity enough to help you more. I just notice you're computing a position but you're considering it a velocity. I suggest you add some code about definition of rocket/planet and their motion, it'll help people to answer